# Meaning of logos for companies/organisations

Tags: logo, design-principles

I have been wondering , while designing a logo for an organisation/company what all should be taken into consideration and what all tools should be used.

For e.g can you tell me the reason behind the design of the following logos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what all companies these logos belong to, its just a part of a bigger assignment where we are supposed to understand the logos, the idea behind them, and probably tell the industry or the exact company the logo belongs to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 "its just a part of a bigger assignment"
```

So, we're doing your homework? ;)

The go-to answer for this is from the godfather of logo design himself, Paul Rand:

Definitely [read the entire article](http://www.paul-rand.com/foundation/thoughts_logosflags/#.T0u5DPXZeuI), but the key section that is oft-quoted is:

> - A logo is a flag, a signature, an escutcheon.
> - A logo doesn’t sell (directly), it identifies.
> - A logo is rarely a description of a business.
> - A logo derives its meaning from the quality of the thing it
>     symbolizes, not the other way around.
> - A logo is less important than the product it signifies; what it means
>     is more important than what it looks like.

A logo represents the company. In the end, the key is that the logo is memorable, easily identifiable, and used consistently. Bonus points if it's aesthetically pleasing, reproducible, and generally well crafted. But in the end, the logo, in and of itself, doesn't have to carry the full weight of the corporate message.

Comment: How many times I've gone through these points with a new client! It's a hard thing to grasp without a ton of examples (which I keep on hand for that purpose), and some -- especially non-profits, for some reason -- just can't let go of the idea that their logo must *depict* who they are.

Comment: Very true! And even worse than non-profits? Government! Maybe in the US at least it's a desire to be democratic to a fault, but nearly every .gov logo ends up being this mess of 6 symbols and 5 fonts and 20 colors.

Comment: Agreed. However two of the three logos Neeraj has posted do describe the company/product.The third is open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see, I'm not familiar with the first and last logo so as a guess the first logo looks like a bird to me, I'd think its some delivery service. The middle one to me is associated to some hair product. And the last looks like wool to me.

No the logo does not have to represent the industry either i.e Apple's apple logo does not represent the tech industry.

Tools you should be using vector graphics software such as Illustrator.

You should look at some colour theory, at least what different colours mean in different cultures. Target colours for customers, i.e. Red in most western cultures are associated with danger whereas in the east it is considered lucky.

Look at the negative space too, i.e the white space in the logos above.

All the logos above look like they are one colour. The first one is just two different shades of black.